# C++ How to print Big letters Horizontally?

Tags: c++

for example, a have this function that prints a big "A"

```
void printA(){
    cout<<"0000000\n0     0\n0     0\n0000000\n0     0\n0     0\n";
}

0000000
0     0
0     0
0000000
0     0
0     0
```

I have all the alphabet, is there a way I can print the big letters horizontally? like:

```
0000000  0000000  0000000
0     0  0     0  0     0
0     0  0     0  0     0
0000000  0000000  0000000
0     0  0     0  0     0
0     0  0     0  0     0
```

the goal of the program is to print the user's input with these big letters, vertically or horizontally.

here is a resumed version of my program:

```
void printA(){
    cout<<"0000000\n0     0\n0     0\n0000000\n0     0\n0     0\n"<<endl;
}

void printChar(char c){
    c = toupper(c);
    if (c=='A')
    printA();

}
int main(){

string sentence;
cout<<"enter sentence: ";
cin>> sentence;

for(unsigned int i = 0; i<sentence.length(); i++) {
    char c = sentence[i];
    if(c=='a')
    printA();
}
return 0;

}
```

I made the letter functions with the "\n" to save lines, another option is to make them like this:

```
void printA(){
    cout << "0000000" << endl;
    cout << "0     0" << endl;
    cout << "0     0" << endl;
    cout << "0000000" << endl;
    cout << "0     0" << endl;
    cout << "0     0" << endl;
}
```

if is not possible to print them next to each other in the way i have them, i will rewrite them, but please tell me how to print them in horizontal form :(
thank you!

I have the following alerts:

```
main.cpp:29:23: warning: range-based 'for' loops only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
         for (char c : text)
                       ^
main.cpp:31:37: warning: 'c' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
             std::cout << alphabet[c - 'A'][line] << "  ";
```

Comment: Console output is performed on a line-by-line basis. So you need to output the 1st line of all the big letters in order, then output the 2nd line of all the letters in order, and so on, in your case for 6 lines total

Comment: Quick Insights: You will have to store each character into a two dimensional array, each element will in this array will be either a `0` or `space` and then you will have, Now if you have to print ABC, first print the 0th Row of A, then 0th Row of B and 0th Row of C, them proceed to printing the next row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can store the lines of your characters in a different format (here, a 2D array) like so:

```
const int LINES_PER_CHAR = 6;
const char* alphabet[][LINES_PER_CHAR] = 
{
    /* A */ { "0000000", "0     0", "0     0", "0000000", "0     0", "0     0" },
    /* B */ { "000 ", "0  0", "0  0", "000 ", "0  0", "0000" }
    ...
};
```

…, then you can print the characters like this:

```
void PrintBigString(const std::string& text)
{
    for (int line = 0; line < LINES_PER_CHAR; ++line)
    {
        for (char c : text)
        {
            std::cout << alphabet[c - 'A'][line] << "  ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Ideally, you should add a sanity check that makes sure that you have the template for the current character in the string.

Variation for non-C++11 compilers:

```
void PrintBigString(const std::string& text)
{
    for (int line = 0; line < LINES_PER_CHAR; ++line)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < text.size(); ++i)
        {
            std::cout << alphabet[text[i] - 'A'][line] << "  ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: will I still be able to print them vertically this way?

Comment: If you print them one after the other (`PrintBigString("A"); PrintBigString("B"); …`).

Comment: well, I have to use a loop to for the user's input, I will try that, or maybe just adding "endl" after each string :/

Comment: Could you please write an expample of how to write “HI” horizontally? So far i can write vertically, i rewrite the code but i dont know how to call the function to print horizontal, im a begginer yet sorry

Comment: `PrintBigString("HI");`

Comment: You accidentally tried to edit my post instead of yours. Have you changed the code? If you use it exactly as I posted and you call `PrintBigString("AA")`, you will get two As next to each other.

Comment: my bad, now I edit my post, I did change some parts to make it run, and maybe that's why I got the combined letters. but other way the code won't run in my c++ could you change it to work on c++98?

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR TIME AND HELP!